# Rails 5 mailform not sending mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, mail-form

I'm trying to build a contact us page in my rails 5 app using the mailform gem. I followed this youtube video explaining the process: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QIoORYeBdhs

However, I can't get the emails to actually deliver in either development or production mode, and I'm not really sure why. Any help would be much appreciated!

Here's what I have:

Welcome.rb:

```
class Welcome < MailForm::Base
    attribute :name, :validate => true
    attribute :email, :validate => /\A([\w+\-].?)+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
    attribute :message, :validate => true
    attribute :nickname, :captcha => true

    def headers 
        {
            :subject => "Contact from About Site",
            :to => "my_email@gmail.com", 
            :from => %("#{name}" <#{email}>)
        }
    end
end
```

welcome_controller:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @welcome = Welcome.new
  end

  def create
    @welcome = Welcome.new(params[:welcome])
    @welcome.request = request
    if @welcome.deliver
        flash.now[:error] = nil
    else
        flash.now[:error] = 'Cannot send message.'
        render :index
    end
  end
end
```

The form itself: (index.html.erb)

```
<section id="contact">
    <div class="container">
        <%= form_for welcome_index_path do |f| %>
            <%= f.label :name %>
            <%= f.text_field :name, required: true %>
            <br>
            <%= f.label :email %>
            <%= f.email_field :email, required: true %>
            <br>
            <%= f.label :message %>
            <%= f.text_area :message, as: :text %>
            <div class="hidden">
                <%= f.label :nickname %>
                <%= f.text_field :nickname, hint: "Leave this field blank" %>
            </div>
            <br>
            <%= f.submit 'Send Message', class: "btn btn-primary btn-large" %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</section>
```

And now my config files:

production.rb, using heroku with sendgrid:

```
# email
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {host: 'https://my_heroku_app.herokuapp.com'}
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port => '587',
    :authentication => :plain, 
    :user_name => ENV["SENDGRID_USERNAME"],
    :password => ENV["SENDGRID_PASSWORD"],
    :domain => 'heroku.com',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true 
  }
```

development.rb, using gem mailcatcher:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {:address => "localhost", :port => 1025}
```

Comment: Everything looks fine. Did you run the `heroku addons:create sendgrid:starter`?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I did - actually however, it seems that it has started working, after about a two day delay. Not really sure why, but it's working now - I had just forgotten to return to this question and mark it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**My own answer** 
It seems actually the code above works just fine, and there was simply a delay in sendgrid starting up. It took about two days, I'm not sure why, but now it's working fine without a real modification to the code